# Package installation on RStudio / R ver 2.11.1

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, cran

I have recently installed R ver. 2.11.1 and RStudio ver. 1.0.143 and tcl/tk ver. 8.5.9 on my Mac (Mac OS 10.7).

1. When RStudio is launched I get the following "warning" message (in RED font):

"WARNING: You are configured to use the CRAN mirror at https://cran.rstudio.com/. This mirror supports secure (HTTPS) downloads however your system is unable to communicate securely with the server (possibly due to out of date certificate files on your system). Falling back to using insecure URL for this mirror."

2. When I try to install a package using the GUI *Install -> Package* , I get the following Error message:

   a. Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : 
   Line starting '
3. When I try to use the Console (by double-clicking on the previous command executed (in the "History" pane) and hitting Enter [the Console shows the command "install.packages("")], the following error message is received:
   a. Error in install.packages : Line starting '
4. If the same command is manually entered (i.e. install.packages(""), I get an error as follows:
   a. R code execution error
   b. Error in normalizePath(dir, winslash = "/", mustWork = TRUE) : 
   unused argument(s) (winslash = "/", mustWork = TRUE)

As suggested in the opening "warning" message (No. 1 above), I have tried the following (after each action rebooted system and tried RStudio):

A. Check if the date and time is set properly. Found correct. Also check box "Set date time automatically" is checked TRUE.

B. Checked firewall setting. Deleted (actually renamed) file "com.apple.alf.plist". On rebooting and starting internet, found that a new file with the same name is created by the system (which I assume is the correct behavior).

C. Created / rebuilt network connections (with a new location name).

D.Cleared certificate management database caches with command (sudo rm /var/db/crls/*cache.db).

E. Turned off OCSP and CRL services in keychain access utility preferences.

F. Checked root certificates in system roots keychain and everything was found ok (apparently so as I did not find any item withthe Blue Plus sign).

Even after the above mentioned steps the situation remains the same as at step 1.

Kindly suggest a way around or possible reason so that I may explore further.

Thanks

Kavi

Comment: Firstly, you must update to the latest version of R 3.4.0.

Comment: As I have submitted in my query (above), I am working with Mac OS X 10.7. As I understand R3.4.0 is meant for Mac OS X 10.11 and above (El Capitan build). Will it be correct to install / update to R 3.4.0 in my case?

Comment: any solution found in this regard ?